go1.23 unique: ran out of hash bits while inserting
When I optimized prometheus, I removed duplicate string labels from the sequence.
When I concurrently called the unique package of go1.23, the insertion caused a panic:
panic: internal/concurrent.HashMapTrie: ran out of hash bits while inserting

goroutine 507 [running]:
    internal/concurrent.(*HashTrieMap[...]).expand(0x16329c0?, 0xc01401ea80, 0xc017143bc0, 0x774483fcd3cff19b, 0x0, 0xc000cf3680)
    /root/tools/go1.23.1/src/internal/concurrent/hashtriemap.go:163 +0x1ea
    internal/concurrent.(*HashTrieMap[...]).LoadOrStore(0x16329c0, {0xc0128e914c, 0x8}, {0x7f27a21a2f18})
    /root/tools/go1.23.1/src/internal/concurrent/hashtriemap.go:142 +0x3c8
    unique.Make[...]({0xc0128e914c, 0x8})
    /root/tools/go1.23.1/src/unique/handle.go:67 +0x1ea
    github.com/baudtime/baudtime/datanode/tsdb.(*Head).getOrCreate(0xc000368d80, 0x17fc4e1ec5dcc73d, {0xc0165e7ea0, 0x6, 0x7})
    /root/go_source/src/github.com/baudtime/baudtime/datanode/tsdb/head.go:1768 +0x1ee

Does unique not provide concurrent calls？
Multiple goroutine concurrent access, do I have to add a lock?

It's not in the package doc but in blog post that it's safe for concurrent use. This may be an implementation bug, you should report it.
